Is this a Minolta SR mount?
I need some help understanding if this lens is a Minolta SR mount lens and if it is possible to adapt it onto my MFT camera. I have this Vivitar 80-200mm 1:4.5 mc Zoom lens. on researching i think it could be a Minolta SR mount lens. I have a minolta MD adaptor (as labeled on the side of the product) that was advertised to fit  Minolta Rokkor (SR / MD / MC) SLR Lenses. So was this false?
From what I can tell, the mounting "wings" on the lens protrude farther out than the opening of the adaptor, and although they are the same shape as the md mount lens I do have, they appear larger. Finally, on the lens that the adaptor does fit, there are no levers for the aperture.

I hope this is enough information, thank you for taking the time to read this and help me out.

I think this might be a Yashica/Contax mount.
It doesn't have the bite out of the correct side of the flange to be an SR.
It doesn't have ears so it's probably not F.
It's actually a bayonet so it's definitely not FL/FD.
It doesn't have a huge ramp on the back so it's not K.
It doesn't have a small ramp/shield on the back and shows no signs of an on-lens stopdown so it's probably not OM.
That kind of leaves Contax/Yashica by process of elimination given the era of mount design shown.  And these look like they mayh match up with other pictures of that mount.

I think it looks most similar to a Contax mount! thanks so much, I'll update with a test fit on an adaptor

got an adaptor in today and it fit, thanks for the help on this one!
